# Resource exception thrown by rally_api on Ruby when querying for artifacts

Tags: ruby, rally

When running rally query, the process quits with the following error message on certain boxes while it works just fin on other boxes. Any help would be appreciated.

Environment - Ruby 1.9xx - rally_api

```
Command return code: 1
Command error output: /home/reaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rally_api-    0.9.16/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:142:in `rescue in send_request': RallyAPI: -     rescued exception - SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A on     request to https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/defect.js with params     {:pagesize=>10, :start=>441, :query=>"(LastUpdateDate > \"2013-06-29T00:00:00+00:00\")",     :fetch=>"Iteration,Capitalizeable,CapBucket,FormattedID,DirectChildrenCount,RevisionHistory,Re    visions,Parent,Project,Portfolio",     :workspace=>"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/workspace/41593629.js",     :project=>"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.42/project/7634660382.js",     :projectScopeUp=>false, :projectScopeDown=>true, :order=>nil} (StandardError)
    from /home/reaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rally_api-    0.9.16/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:136:in `send_request'
    from /home/reaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rally_api-    0.9.16/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:196:in `block (2 levels) in run_single_thread'
    from /home/reaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rally_api-    0.9.16/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:195:in `each'
    from /home/reaper/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/rally_api-    0.9.16/lib/rally_api/rally_json_connection.rb:195:in `block in run_single_thread'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may see if this simple ruby code that only tests the connection fails with the same error too:

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new() headers.name = "My Utility"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "password"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "P"
config[:version] = "1.43"
config[:headers] = headers 

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
puts @rally.user
```

I have seen the same error reported and a proxy turned out to be the culprit. If it runs from some computers and fails from others that narrows down the potential source of the problem to the environment where the script is run - perhaps there have been  proxy configuration changes.

If you have a proxy between the machine on which you run your script and rally1.rallydev.com, please verify if http_proxy environment variable is set to the current valid values.
Normally the environment variables http_proxy should be set as follows.

a) for authenticating proxy:

```
yourusername:yourpassword@IPAddress:Port
```

b) for non-authenticating proxy.

```
IPAddress:Port
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate your help - however, this didn't work for me. The small program that you suggested in the beginning returns immediately.  At this point I am wondering if I am querying for too much data, trying to re-architect the program to do it in chunks.